# Apache SSL Rewrite with Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm attempting to setup an SSL redirect in Apache using RewriteEngine that will do the following:

- Redirect traffic to either http://mydomain.com or http://www.mydomain.com to use HTTPS
- Redirect traffic to any other subdomain https://*.mydomain.com to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

My reasoning for this is that I'm developing a project that's using a free SSL certificate until launch. This certificate covers the base domain, but none of the wildcard subdomains, and it's a pain to need to bypass the warning every time I visit one of the subdomains.

Edit:
I believe I'm close here, but I still can't get the HTTPS to HTTP redirect to work properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect domain and www to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain.com [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Redirect wildcard subdomains to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. By moving these rules from the sites-available/default file to an .htaccess inside of the website root, I was able to get this working properly.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect domain and www to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain.com [or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Redirect wildcard subdomains to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for these rules, helped to get a wildcard domain-specific redirect going for me.  Did you add the HTTPS->HTTP redirect within the SSL portion of the apache virtualhost config?  Might be why it didn't work without it being in .htaccess.  It's more performant to put it in the apache config if you can.